# Javascript & HTML - Passing dropdown index value as object property returns undefined

Tags: javascript

I'm brand new to this language and I've hit a road block. I've searched for a few hours about this specific problem but can't seem to figure out why my situation is so hard to fix. I'm sure I just need a set of eyes that knows what they're looking at.

I'm trying to pass the index of a dropdown select into my Code.gs function so that I can use it elsewhere to select a certain row of a data in a spreadsheet. I set up the object driverPicked and give it the property selected, and then hunt for the selected index property. As I'm really new to this, I'm having a hard time understanding the consequences of nesting properties like this and could use a clue as to how to solve the "TypeError: Cannot read property 'selected' of undefined (line 39, file "Code")" error I've been getting for hours now.

There are so many similar answers but I can't sort out exactly how they apply to me - so forgive me for that!

```
var url = "REDACTED";

function doGet(e){

//var x = document.getElementById("driver").selectedIndex;  

var driverIndex = userClicked();
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Results_2019");
var listDrivers = ws.getRange(4,1,ws.getRange("A3").getDataRegion().getLastRow(),1).getValues();
var infoHeading = ws.getRange(3, 1, 1, 8).getValues();
var driverInfo = ws.getRange(driverIndex, 1, 1 ,8).getValues();


var tmp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("page"); 
tmp.title = "GLTC Driver List";
//tmp.listDrivers = listDrivers.map(function(r){r[0];});
tmp.listDrivers = [].concat.apply([], listDrivers);
tmp.infoHeading = [].concat.apply([], infoHeading);
tmp.driverInfo = [].concat.apply([], driverInfo);
tmp.driverIndex = driverIndex;


return tmp.evaluate();

}


function include(filename){
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
}


function userClicked(driverPicked) {
  console.log(driverPicked); 
  var driverName = driverPicked.value;
  return driverName;
}


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
     <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
    <?!= include("page-css"); ?>
  </head>
  <body>

    <h1><?= title; ?></h1>

    <div class="input-field">
  <select id="driver">
    <option disabled selected>Choose Driver</option>
    <? for(var i=0;i<listDrivers.length;i++){ ?>
      <option class="selected">
        <?= listDrivers[i]; ?>
      </option>
      <? } ?>
  </select>
</div>

  <h5><?= infoHeading; ?></h5>

  <h5><?= driverInfo; ?></h5>

  <h5><?= driverIndex; ?></h5>

<script>  

document.getElementById("driver").addEventListener("change", doStuff); // add onchange listener to the select element instead of options

function doStuff(event) {
  var driverPicked = {};

  driverPicked.driver = event.target.value;
  driverPicked.selected = event.target.options.selectedIndex;
  userClicked(driverPicked);
}


  </script>

    <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <?!= include("page-js"); ?>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what's the error you are getting now?

Comment: It's the same thing, TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined (line 36, file "Code")

Comment: but that seems to indicate the file `code` cannot be found.. are you sure this file is located where you think it is, and that it is being loaded correctly?

Comment: I'm working in Google's web app UI, and they are all part of the same project. I am able to pass other arguments back and forth like 'listDrivers' (Which is the thing that gets looped in the HTML).

Comment: Hmmm, weird... What is happening on line 36 of that file? can you add a console.log(<name of variable>) line just before this line?

Comment: It is the line that contains var driverName = driverPicked.value;

Comment: Ok, so... driverPicked has only two attributes `driverPicked.driver` and `driverPicked.selected` - but you are trying to print out `drivedPicked.value` which is undefined - can you print out `console.log(driverPicked);` ? and check the console to see if it contains the values you expect?

Comment: The result of that console.log statement returns 'undefined' in the log.

Comment: Well, something is amiss... this is inside the `userClicked(...)` function right?

Comment: That is correct. There's a tutorial I was following on YouTube I was following almost exactly that had no issue with the object.value in the .gs file. Have no idea what's up.

Comment: can you print the same variable before invoking the function then?

Comment: I ran the console.log(driverPicked); on the line before userClicked() and didn't get any output. I ran it before the function definition in Code.gs and, as expected there, recieved "driverPicked" is undefined, because it's not in scope.

Comment: well, that indicates our function is not the one calling it - are there multiple definitions of it? (one overriding the other one, perhaps?) - can you rename the function from `userClicked(...)` to `myUserClicked(...)` ... we just need to narrow it down further (at this point, it's just process of elimination, walking backwards to find out the discrepancy between what we see and what's being executed)

Comment: There is only one definition of it - and changing to myUserClicked had no effect on changing the error. I'm starting to think I need to do this in a fundamentally different way - to save myself (and you) time. I appreciate all your help and your time - and unless you have other ideas, I'll have to approach this some other way. Thank you! -Kyle

Comment: I ran out of ideas, there’s something not connecting here and I’m afraid I ran out of time to help you out with this

Answer (score 1):

A few issues with the code:

1. DOM elements' ids have to be unique, so when rendering options you either need to add index to id or use a class name instead.
2. Instead of `click` use `change` event for `select` elements.
3. You can access event object as an argument inside `doStuff` function instead of querying DOM elements manually. 
   I'm not sure why would you need to get an index, but in order to get driver's name you can do smth like this:

```
<div class="input-field">
  <select id="driver">
    <option disabled selected>Choose Driver</option>
    <? for(var i=0;i<listDrivers.length;i++){ ?>
      <option class="selected"> // use class instead of id here
        <?= listDrivers[i]; ?>
      </option>
      <? } ?>
  </select>
</div>
```

```
document.getElementById("driver").addEventListener("change", doStuff); // add onchange listener to the select element instead of options

function doStuff(event) {
  var driverPicked = {};

  driverPicked.driver = event.target.value;
  driverPicked.selected = event.target.options.selectedIndex;

  google.script.run.userClicked(driverPicked);
}

function userClicked(driverPicked) {

  var driverName = driverPicked.value;
  return driverName;
}
```

Here's a runnable example with some mock `select` options:

```js
document.getElementById("driver").addEventListener("change", doStuff); // add onchange listener to the select element instead of options

function doStuff(event) {
  var driverPicked = {};

  driverPicked.driver = event.target.value;
  driverPicked.selected = event.target.options.selectedIndex;
  userClicked(driverPicked);
}

function userClicked(driverPicked) {
  console.log(driverPicked); 
  var driverName = driverPicked.value;
  return driverName;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-field">
  <select id="driver">
    <option disabled selected>Choose Driver</option>
      <option class="selected"> Driver 1</option>
      <option class="selected"> Driver 2</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! The reason why I was looking for the index and not the name, is because I just need to know how far down the list the name is, not what the name text is. When I know how far down the list the name is, I'll use that number to reference that specific row in a Google Sheet. This code you supplied still has the same error, this time saying value is undefined in driverPicked.value in Code.gs. I appreciate the help and the clarifications - just not quite there yet!

Comment: You can get the index of selected option via `event.target.options.selectedIndex`. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

There a a few simplifications done here.  Main one would be that instead of invoking the function via `google.script.run` I am just directly calling it.

**UPDATE**

I forgot to include in the initial response.  Element `id`s are supposed to be unique.  If you loop through all your elements and do not change their id value then you are crafting incorrect HTML and the function `getElementById(...)` will return an array of elements instead of just on (thus, the rest of the code will not work as expected)

**See demo below**

```js
document.getElementById("driver").addEventListener("change", doStuff);

function doStuff() {
  var driverPicked = {};
  selectBox = document.getElementById("driver");

  driverPicked = selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex];
  console.log('User changed value to: ');
  console.log(driverPicked);

  // will this work on other browsers?
  // google.script.run.userClicked(driverPicked);
  // I am using this instead for demo purposes
  userClicked(driverPicked);
}

function userClicked(driverPicked) {
  var driverName = driverPicked.value;
  var driverText = driverPicked.text;
  console.log('name/value: ' + driverName + ' text: ' + driverText);

  return driverName;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-field">
  <select id="driver">
    <option disabled>Choose Driver</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
    <option value="4">Four</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Appreciate the help - I'm still getting an undefined reference with driverPicked.value and driverPicked.text. I see that your snippet works perfect - I wonder if there's something I'm not understanding about Google's Web App constructor and how it passes things between the page.html and Code.gs

Comment: You will have to post more details on your question then.  If you run my example/code you will notice I do not get the same errors.  Something in your code is not included in your question and it's interfering.

Comment: @Kyle_H15 oh, I also added a note about unique `ID`s in HTML... maybe that's the reason why?

Comment: I've updated the post with the entire Code.gs and page.html. There's a css page too but I don't think that could interfere with it? Forgive me for the very obvious lack of understanding. This is an optimistic project for being so new to JS. Thanks for your time!